# Maximo - how to add wotrack worklog to start center resultset list view on a portlet

Tags: maximo

I have a start center with a portlet and a resultset to show open work orders. I show:

- Wonum
- description
- created date

Now I would like to add related wo worklog

I created a relationship on workorder database objects

Added dot notation on oracle, and I also added an entry on the integration object. I see the column but it is blank.

Do I need to restart app server?

Comment: Hi Fabe :) Happy New Year. You can have multiple entries in a worklog, Are you going to show only the most recent worklog entry?

Comment: Hi Sun, Happy new 2016. yes, the most recent.

Comment: which column did you add?

Comment: Hi. User are asking for this change. Could yoi help me? I see the worklogs are avaolable under ROS but do not see it when I try to select it on the resultset col? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar issue. Trying to add Failure Remarks to WOTRACK. Might not be possible with some SQL: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21429286